# Distortion of body in Schwarzschild black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, tidal-effect

Suppose I toss a cloud of matter into a Schwarzschild black hole; for the sake of argument, have it be timelike dust. As we know, the dust is "spaghettified" by tidal forces: simultaneously compressed in the tangential and elongated in the radial directions relative to the singularity.

Consider any particular volume in the dust cloud. Is its fate thus to become infinitely *sparse* (due to the radial elongation) or infinitely *dense* (due to the tangential compression)?

EDIT: It has been correctly pointed out that the tidal forces remain always finite, so the cloud is not infinitely anything. The modified question: is the net effect on the cloud a rarefaction or a compression?

Comment: It shouldn't become infinitely anything before meeting the singularity, as all points outside the singularity experience finite tidal forces.

Comment: @Asher I mean, which state does it (more closely) approach on its way to the singularity.

Comment: @Asher Well I'm pretty sure it won't become infinite in this case, but in general it can. Even finite tidal forces can compress pressureless material into infinitesimal caustic sheets in finite time.

Answer (score 0):

The volume of your dust cloud will not change. The shape changes but the volume does not, so the density of the cloud remains constant.

The Schwarzschild solution is a vacuum solution and the Ricci tensor is everywhere zero. If you look at [section 5.2 of this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0401099) it shows that the change in volume of an infinitesimal volume element is proportional to the Ricci tensor, so when the Ricci tensor is zero the volume is constant.

Comment: I thought the vorticity, tidal, and divergence terms of the [Raychaudhuri equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raychaudhuri_equation) would vanish (at least when starting at rest at infinity), leaving $\dot\theta = -\theta^2/3 - 2\sigma^2 < 0$. @brucesmitherson Doesn't this mean density will increase?

Comment: @John On second thought there's a subtlety about whether we are comoving with the dust while measuring its volume (Raychaudhuri applies) or using some other coordinates. So I'm not sure how much disagreement there is.

Comment: Perhaps this has to do with some vagueness in the term volume, but I don't see how this can be right. Certainly it is not the case that the density of a dust cloud in a general vacuum solution is constant. This would contradict the existence of tides.

Comment: @AGML yes I got it wrong, I erased the comments too

Comment: @John Rennie: Its the second derivative that will be zero, that means that the volume will change linearly.

Comment: @MBN: a linear rate of change means the volume would go to infinity if we extrapolate out to infinity ...

Comment: @JohnRennie The equation in question involves a covariant derivative; it thus seems to me to imply that the deviation is proportional to the Ricci tensor *as well as some function of the Christoffel symbols*, and the latter are nonzero in vacuum unless we are in Minkowski space. This would be more consistent with, for example, the fact that the density of a gas cloud approaching the Earth increases due to tidal forces.